# How to hide top panel in elementary os?

Tags: wingpanel

How to hide top panel in elementary os? This is boring when I maximize a browser and see top black panel over browser.

Answer (score 1):

I have a fork of wingpanel with [autohide](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/93).

Unless you are using Archlinux, clone the [git repository](https://github.com/quequotion/wingpanel), then build and install according to the README.

For Archlinux, it is packaged in the AUR: [wingpanel-standalone-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/wingpanel-standalone-git/)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this if you toggle fullscreen mode of the application you are using. You can set a keyboard shortcut for this in System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Window > Toggle Fullscreen and it works for all applications not only for the web browsers.